# Cassandra Gossip is increasing pending tasks

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Since last week we are seeing lot of pending tasks increased in cassandra. I know there are just the WARN messages but all of my logs are flooding with these messages on all the nodes in the cluster. How to resolve this issue. We are already using phi_convict_threshold value 12.

```
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:31,008 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 6996 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:32,109 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7001 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:33,210 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7004 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:34,311 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7007 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:35,435 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7010 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:36,537 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7011 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:37,638 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7014 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:38,739 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7018 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:39,840 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7022 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:40,941 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7026 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:42,042 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7030 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:43,147 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7033 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:44,254 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7035 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:45,354 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7041 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
 WARN [GossipTasks:1] 2014-10-27 15:24:46,459 Gossiper.java (line 637) Gossip stage has 7143 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually those messages appear alongside other gossip messages. It looks like you might have used grep there to just extract the warnings. Can you share a snippet of your log to see if there are other adjacent Gossip messages?

Comment: Looks like the original poster has gone away. I actually have a node in this state right now, but not clear why. And no, no grepping; that is exactly what my log looks like too (DSE Cassandra 2.0.11).

Comment: Do you have any other messages in the logs? Also what does nodetool status show for the cluster?

Comment: Has someone found the cause? I also have one node with these strange log records.

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrade from 2.1.8 to 2.1.9 has solved the problem.

Possible reason is the bug [CASSANDRA-9279](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9279)